# XML-RPC request with struct in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, wordpress, struct, xml-rpc

I'm trying to use xmlrpc with wordpress to get post of a specific custom type (called a collection).

The Wordpress API doc states:

wp.getPosts

```
Parameters:
int blog_id
string username
string password
struct filter: Optional.
   string post_type
   string post_status
   int number
   int offset
   string orderby
   string order
array fields: Optional.
```

My problem is in forming a struct with strings in objc:

I am wanting to do something like this:

```
// in .h

typedef struct{
    string post_type;
    string post_status;
    int number;
    int offset;
    string orderby;
    string order;
} wp_filter;

// in .m

wp_filter filter = {@"collection", @"", ... , ... ,@"",@""};
NSArray *fieldsArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"post_title", nil];
NSArray *postParams = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"0", username, password, filter, fieldsArray, nil];
XMLRPCRequest *reqCollections =[[XMLRPCRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:server]];

[reqCollections setMethod:@"wp.getPosts" withParameters:postParams];

XMLRPCResponse *customPostResponse = [XMLRPCConnection sendSynchronousXMLRPCRequest:reqCollections error:nil];

if ([[customPostResponse object] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]){
    NSArray *collections = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[customPostResponse object]];
    NSLog(@"number of collections %i",[collections count]);
    for (int i = 0; i < [collections count]; i++) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [[collections objectAtIndex:i] description] );
    }
}
else {
    NSLog(@"response description %@",[[customPostResponse object ] description]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about the XML-RPC WordPress API, but `structs` are C constructs but not Cocoa `NSObjects`, so you cannot embed them in an `NSArray`.

So the `[NSArray arrayWithObjects:..., filter, ..., nil]` line is invalid, because `filter` is a `wp_filter` struct.

I think that the "struct" that is mentioned in the API documentation is more some pseudo-code to explain the data structure / organization. Obviously you need to "translate" that concept into Cocoa objects.

What you might try is to convert your C struct into either an `NSArray` and pass the parameters in the same order as the API expect, or more likely to convert your struct into an `NSDictionary`, whose keys are the name of the structs fields, and values are obviously your struct's field values.

Moreover, to encapsulate integers into Cocoa objects, you should use the `NSNumber` class instead of converting your integers into `NSStrings`.

---

So this sould give something like this:

```
NSDictionary* filter = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
    @"collection", @"post_type",
    @"", @"post_status",
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:number], @"number",
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:offset], @"offset",
    @"", @"orderby",
    @"", @"order",
    nil];
NSArray *postParams = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], // blog_id
    username,
    password,
    filter,
    [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"post_title"], // fieldsArray
    nil];
```

Or, if you use the recent LLVM compiler that allows you to use Modern Objective-C, you can use the more concise syntax:

```
NSDictionary* filter = @{
    @"post_type": @"collection",
    @"post_status": @"",
    @"number": @(number)
    @"offset": @(offset)
    @"orderby": @"",
    @"order": @""};
NSArray *postParams = @[ @0, username, password, filter, @[@"post_title"]];
```

I even bet that for parameters that you don't want to set in your call, like the `"orderby"` and `"order"` parameters for example, you can skip the keys and avoid to set them in the dictionary.

Once again, I never used the Wordpress XML-RPC API, but as I understand the documentation, if this does not work the solution should be pretty close to something like this (for example I may be wrong and you may have to use an `NSArray` instead of an `NSDictionary` for the "filter" pseudo-struct mentioned in the doc; what you quoted from the documentation in your question is not really sufficient to tell which has to be used when using it thru Cocoa).

Comment: Thanks for your extremely helpful response. However, I'd already tried an NSArray & using an NSDictionary as you suggested seems to get ignored by the response (i.e. returns ALL posts of non specific post types). I'll look further into the XMLRPCRequest class to see how it formats the parameters.

Comment: Although I can't seem to get it respond correctly, it seems as thought your answer is correct, the xmlrpc encoder formats the key value pairs into a wrapper named <struct>